# DSpace XMLUI Batch uploader: Upload fails due to "Unable to create mapfile"

Tags: dspace

I'm trying to upload a SimpleArchiveFormat zip-File through the batch upload interface in XMLUI (DSpace 5.2), but the upload fails("Import failed"). 
The log says:

```
org.dspace.app.xmlui.aspect.administrative.FlowBatchImportUtils @
BatchImportUI Unable to create mapfile
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

Where is DSpace trying to create the mapfile? It sounds like the omnipresent "tomcat can't write to that directory" issue, but that's just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dspace-install]-folder has to be writable by the tomcat user for DSpace to create (and delete) the `org.dspace.app.batchitemimport.work.dir`-directory.

Comment: Note the guidance in the DSpace installation instructions for the tomcat user: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-ServletEngine(ApacheTomcat7orlater,Jetty,CauchoResinorequivalent)

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on my server.

After the file is uploaded, it is transferred to [dspace-install]/imports

This appears to be a transient directory.  Once the file is processed (successfully or not), this folder is deleted.

Comment: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L839-L841

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, the "imports" directory was missing in my [dspace-install] folder. Creating it eliminated the error, making way for a new one that i don't understand: `/home/dspace/dspace/imports/frprot.zip/item_001/dublin_core.xml (No such file or directory)` (the file is in the .zip)

Comment: Try exporting a small collection (admin menu option).  Examine the structure and format of the export file to see if that helps with troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, @terrywb - that helped me with another question.